# XML upload while parsing

Tags: php, xml

Is it possible to have an upload box on a website where as the XML file is being uploaded it can be parsed at the same time. So for example the values could start to populate say a div rather than waiting for the complete file to be uploaded and then parse.

Comment: Also i said php but it doesnt have to be.

Answer (score 1):

No, the file needs to be completely uploaded before you can use the `move_uploaded_file` function to move it to a temp directory for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the [Magic Parser](http://www.magicparser.com/) and as far as i can remember, it does have that option.